# Connected to container mycontainer. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session. - How to press ^]?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Soure: http://0pointer.net/blog/systemd-for-administrators-part-xxi.html

> Connected to container mycontainer. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.

How to do that?

What's the name of that key combination?

How to press `^]`? Which actual key combination is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL key on keyboard. Meaning CTRL and the "]" key together.

Comment: Sometimes `CTRL + 5` does the trick for me.